# AS3: Touch and gotoAndStop

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

So I am trying to do a simple gotoAndStop with some touch event's but after every time the user is done doing the certain touch events I want to reset the image back to the first frame, but I'm not to sure on how to do this using touch events. Here's my code.

```
import flash.ui.Multitouch;
import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;
import flash.events.TransformGestureEvent;

Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;

square_mc.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_PAN, onPan);
square_mc.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ROTATE, onRotate);
square_mc.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ZOOM, onZoom);

function onPan (e:TransformGestureEvent):void{
    square_mc.y += e.offsetY;
    square_mc.x += e.offsetX;
}

function onRotate (e:TransformGestureEvent):void{
    square_mc.rotation += e.rotation;
    square_mc.gotoAndStop(2);
}

function onZoom (e:TransformGestureEvent):void{
    square_mc.scaleX *= e.scaleX;
    square_mc.scaleY *= e.scaleY;
}
```

Comment: What is the image? `square_mc`?  I only see one `gotoAndStop` and it isn't the first frame?

Comment: square_mc is the image, and now I haven't tried to put the reset back to the first frame because because i'm unsure on how to do it

Comment: just put `square_mc.gotoAndStop(1);` at the end of each of your gesture handlers (onPan, onRotate, onZoom)

Comment: where exactly? not working if im putting it in the right spot

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import flash.events.TouchEvent
```

Then create an event listeners to detect if the user stops touching the tablet:

```
stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, endTouch);

function endTouch (e:TouchEvent):void{
    square_mc.y = CONSTANT;
    square_mc.x = CONSTANT;
    square_mc.rotation = CONSTANT;
    square_mc.scaleX = CONSTANT;
    square_mc.scaleY = CONSTANT;
    square_mc.gotoAndStop(CONSTANT);
}
```

where "constant" is a number you define yourself

Comment: Still stay on whatever the last frame was.. Any idea why? I see what your trying to do though. But just so you know I all ready have another stage eventlistener for when i draw a line

Comment: @user3727417 It's probably because the function is called before onPan, onRotate, and onZoom is called, so the called values are pretty much overwritten. Maybe add a [setTimeout](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#setTimeout%28%29) in there?

Answer (score -1):

Only make a function to reset you image and call function on onPan onRotate and onZoom.